# iOS 7 automatically downloaded to phone after downgrading to iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios

I have downgraded my iPhone 4 from iOS 7 to iOS 6.1.3, but when it went back to iOS 6, the Software Update section of Settings is showing that iOS 7 is automatically downloading again. I tried to downgrade my phone again and again but it's not working.

Comment: This is how things are now. iOS will always download and store the latest update, which as you found, occupies quite a bit of space. You will need to jailbreak (which disables OTA updates in 6.1.3) to avoid this. There is no other way. No matter how many times you restore, iOS will ping Apple's servers and if it finds an update, it will pull it to your device.

Answer (score 1):

Your iPhone software update is trying to be smart by downloading the update in the background for iOS 7. What it is trying to do is make sure that the update is already on your device, and all you need to do is press the update button, without waiting for a download to finish.

You aren't in danger of loosing your downgrade - your phone will always ask your permission before *installing* any update. You probably won't be able to keep it from *downloading* the update, though.